# Probability of 2 People Winning a Giveaway

Tags: probability

My friend and I entered a giveaway and we both won. There were **329** entries (including mine and my friend's) and **10 different winners** were announced. I submitted **2 entries** and my friend only submitted **1 entry**. The sampling had no replacement. What was the probability that my friend and I both won?

Edit: I was thinking of using $\dfrac{10}{329}\left(\dfrac{9}{327}\right)$ but I'm not sure how to go from there. It seems like this would work if I won the first one and my friend was picked immediately after, but it's possible that he wins the 10th pick instead of the 2nd pick. How do I modify my work to incorporate that?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I made changes to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are $10$ different winners, for both you and your friend to win, you must select one winning ticket and one losing ticket given that your friend selected a winning ticket.

Since there are $10$ winning tickets among the $329$ entries, the probability of your friend winning (before the results were known) was $10/329$.  That leaves $328$ tickets.  You can select two of them in $\binom{328}{2}$ ways.  The number of ways you can select one winning ticket and one losing ticket from among the nine remaining winning tickets and $319$ losing tickets is $9 \cdot 319$.  Hence, the probability that both you and your friend would win (before the results were known) was
$$\frac{10}{329} \cdot \frac{9 \cdot 319}{\dbinom{328}{2}}$$
where
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements.

If you are not familiar with that notation, suppose your friend selects first.  The probability that your friend wins is $10/329$.  Given that your friend selected a winning ticket, exactly one of your entries is a winning ticket if you pick a winning ticket followed by a losing ticket or if you pick a losing ticket followed by a winning ticket.  Therefore, the probability that you both win is
$$\frac{10}{329} \cdot \frac{9}{328} \cdot \frac{319}{327} + \frac{10}{329} \cdot \frac{319}{328} \cdot \frac{9}{327}$$

Comment: ^It's possible that he picked two winning tickets.

Comment: @Nate The problem explicitly states that there are $10$ different winners of the $10$ winning tickets, so he had to select one winning ticket and one losing ticket.